# getAttribute or getText

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a script to sign up for a facebook account which is done automatically as in the picture below:

[image]

I now want to extract what I have written so I have tried the following code but nothin appears?

```
    WebElement fNameText = driver.findElement(By.name("firstname"));
    String Txt = fNameText.getText();
    System.out.println(Txt);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String Txt = fNameText.getAttribute("value");` to get the value in the textbox